# Can I specify the output in Test2 test

Tags: perl, testing

Is there a way to edit the following [Test2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test2) test:

```sh
perl -MTest2::V0 -MRegexp::Common=URI -wE 'is( shift, match $RE{URI}, "should match a URI" )' foo
```

Such that the `CHECK` output is less verbose than this:

```
# Seeded srand with seed '20200813' from local date.
1..1
not ok 1 - should match a URI
# Failed test 'should match a URI'
# at -e line 1.
# +-----+----+-------------------------------------------------------+-----+
# | GOT | OP | CHECK                                                 | LNs |
# +-----+----+-------------------------------------------------------+-----+
# | foo | =~ | (?:(?:(?:file)://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][ | 1   |
# |     |    | -a-zA-Z0-9]*)?[a-zA-Z0-9])[.])*(?:[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9 |     |
# |     |    | ]*[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z]))|(?:[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[ |     |
# |     |    | .][0-9]+))|localhost)?)(?:/(?:(?:(?:(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9$_. |     |
# |     |    | +!*'(),:@&=]|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]))*)(?:/(?:(?: |     |
# |     |    | [-a-zA-Z0-9$_.+!*'(),:@&=]|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9] |     |
# |     |    | ))*))*)))))|(?:(?:telnet)://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[-a-zA-Z0- |     |
# |     |    | 9$_.+!*'(),;?&=]|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]))*))(?::( |     |
# |     |    | ?:(?:(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9$_.+!*'(),;?&=]|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9][a- |     |
# |     |    | fA-F0-9]))*)))?)@)?(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][- |     |
# |     |    | a-zA-Z0-9]*)?[a-zA-Z0-9])[.])*(?:[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9] |     |
# |     |    | *[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z]))|(?:[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[. |     |
# |     |    | ][0-9]+)))(?::(?:(?:[0-9]+)))?)(?:/)?)|(?:(?:https?): |     |
# |     |    | //(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9]*)?[a-zA-Z |     |
# |     |    | 0-9])[.])*(?:[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z |     |
# |     |    | ])[.]?)|(?:[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+)))(?::(? |     |
# |     |    | :(?:[0-9]*)))?(?:/(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.!~* |     |
# |     |    | '():@&=+$,]+|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]))*)(?:;(?:(?: |     |
# |     |    | [a-zA-Z0-9\-_.!~*'():@&=+$,]+|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0 |     |
# |     |    | -9]))*))*)(?:/(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.!~*'():@&=+$,]+| |     |
# |     |    | (?:%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]))*)(?:;(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-_ |     |
# |     |    | .!~*'():@&=+$,]+|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]))*))*))*) |     |
# |     |    | )(?:[?](?:(?:(?:[;/?:@&=+$,a-zA-Z0-9\-_.!~*'()]+|(?:% |     |
# |     |    | [a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]))*)))?))?)|(?:(?:gopher)://(?: |     |
# |     |    | (?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9]*)?[a-zA-Z0-9]) |     |
# |     |    | [.])*(?:[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z]))|( |     |
# |     |    | ?:[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+)))(?::(?:(?:[0-9] |     |
# |     |    | +)))?/(?:(?:(?:[0-9+IgT]))(?:(?:(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9$_.+!*' |     |
# |     |    | (),:@&=]+|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]))*))))|(?:(?:pop |     |
# |     |    | )://(?:(?:(?:(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9$_.+!*'(),&=~]+|(?:%[a-fA- |     |
# |     |    | F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]))+))(?:;AUTH=(?:[*]|(?:(?:(?:[-a-zA- |     |
# |     |    | Z0-9$_.+!*'(),&=~]+|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]))+)|(? |     |
# |     |    | :[+](?:APOP|(?:(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9$_.+!*'(),&=~]+|(?:%[a-f |     |
# |     |    | A-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]))+))))))?@)?(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-z |     |
# |     |    | A-Z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9]*)?[a-zA-Z0-9])[.])*(?:[a-zA-Z][-a |     |
# |     |    | -zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z]))|(?:[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[. |     |
# |     |    | ][0-9]+[.][0-9]+)))(?::(?:(?:[0-9]+)))?)|(?:(?:prospe |     |
# |     |    | ro)://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9]*)?[a- |     |
# |     |    | zA-Z0-9])[.])*(?:[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a- |     |
# |     |    | zA-Z]))|(?:[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+)))(?::(? |     |
# |     |    | :(?:[0-9]+)))?/(?:(?:(?:(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9$_.+!*'(),?:@&= |     |
# |     |    | ]|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]))*)(?:/(?:(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9 |     |
# |     |    | $_.+!*'(),?:@&=]|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]))*))*))(? |     |
# |     |    | :(?:;(?:(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9$_.+!*'(),?:@&]|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9] |     |
# |     |    | [a-fA-F0-9]))*)=(?:(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9$_.+!*'(),?:@&]|(?:% |     |
# |     |    | [a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]))*))*))|(?:(?:wais)://(?:(?:(? |     |
# |     |    | :(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9]*)?[a-zA-Z0-9])[.])* |     |
# |     |    | (?:[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z]))|(?:[0- |     |
# |     |    | 9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+)))(?::(?:(?:[0-9]+)))? |     |
# |     |    | /(?:(?:(?:(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9$_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9][a |     |
# |     |    | -fA-F0-9]))*))(?:[?](?:(?:(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9$_.+!*'(),;:@ |     |
# |     |    | &=]|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]))*))|/(?:(?:(?:[-a-zA- |     |
# |     |    | Z0-9$_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]))*))/(?:(? |     |
# |     |    | :(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9$_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9] |     |
# |     |    | ))*)))?))|(?:(?:tel):(?:(?:(?:[+](?:[0-9\-.()]+)(?:;i |     |
# |     |    | sub=[0-9\-.()]+)?(?:;postd=[0-9\-.()*#ABCDwp]+)?(?:(? |     |
# |     |    | :;(?:phone-context)=(?:(?:(?:[+][0-9\-.()]+)|(?:[0-9\ |     |
# |     |    | -.()*#ABCDwp]+))|(?:(?:[!'E-OQ-VX-Z_e-oq-vx-z~]|(?:%( |     |
# |     |    | ?:2[124-7CFcf]|3[AC-Fac-f]|4[05-9A-Fa-f]|5[1-689A-Fa- |     |
# |     |    | f]|6[05-9A-Fa-f]|7[1-689A-Ea-e])))(?:[!'()*\-.0-9A-Z_ |     |
# |     |    | a-z~]+|(?:%(?:2[1-9A-Fa-f]|3[AC-Fac-f]|[4-6][0-9A-Fa- |     |
# |     |    | f]|7[0-9A-Ea-e])))*)))|(?:;(?:tsp)=(?: |(?:(?:(?:[A-Z |     |
# |     |    | a-z](?:(?:(?:[-A-Za-z0-9]+)){0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?)(?:[. |     |
# |     |    | ](?:[A-Za-z](?:(?:(?:[-A-Za-z0-9]+)){0,61}[A-Za-z0-9] |     |
# |     |    | )?))*))))|(?:;(?:(?:[!'*\-.0-9A-Z_a-z~]+|%(?:2[13-7AB |     |
# |     |    | DEabde]|3[0-9]|4[1-9A-Fa-f]|5[AEFaef]|6[0-9A-Fa-f]|7[ |     |
# |     |    | 0-9ACEace]))*)(?:=(?:(?:(?:(?:[!'*\-.0-9A-Z_a-z~]+|%( |     |
# |     |    | ?:2[13-7ABDEabde]|3[0-9]|4[1-9A-Fa-f]|5[AEFaef]|6[0-9 |     |
# |     |    | A-Fa-f]|7[0-9ACEace]))*)(?:[?](?:(?:[!'*\-.0-9A-Z_a-z |     |
# |     |    | ~]+|%(?:2[13-7ABDEabde]|3[0-9]|4[1-9A-Fa-f]|5[AEFaef] |     |
# |     |    | |6[0-9A-Fa-f]|7[0-9ACEace]))*))?)|(?:%22(?:(?:%5C(?:[ |     |
# |     |    | a-zA-Z0-9\-_.!~*'()]|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])))|[a |     |
# |     |    | -zA-Z0-9\-_.!~*'()]+|(?:%(?:[01][a-fA-F0-9])|2[013-9A |     |
# |     |    | -Fa-f]|[3-9A-Fa-f][a-fA-F0-9]))*%22)))?))*)|(?:[0-9\- |     |
# |     |    | .()*#ABCDwp]+(?:;isub=[0-9\-.()]+)?(?:;postd=[0-9\-.( |     |
# |     |    | )*#ABCDwp]+)?(?:;(?:phone-context)=(?:(?:(?:[+][0-9\- |     |
# |     |    | .()]+)|(?:[0-9\-.()*#ABCDwp]+))|(?:(?:[!'E-OQ-VX-Z_e- |     |
# |     |    | oq-vx-z~]|(?:%(?:2[124-7CFcf]|3[AC-Fac-f]|4[05-9A-Fa- |     |
# |     |    | f]|5[1-689A-Fa-f]|6[05-9A-Fa-f]|7[1-689A-Ea-e])))(?:[ |     |
# |     |    | !'()*\-.0-9A-Z_a-z~]+|(?:%(?:2[1-9A-Fa-f]|3[AC-Fac-f] |     |
# |     |    | |[4-6][0-9A-Fa-f]|7[0-9A-Ea-e])))*)))(?:(?:;(?:phone- |     |
# |     |    | context)=(?:(?:(?:[+][0-9\-.()]+)|(?:[0-9\-.()*#ABCDw |     |
# |     |    | p]+))|(?:(?:[!'E-OQ-VX-Z_e-oq-vx-z~]|(?:%(?:2[124-7CF |     |
# |     |    | cf]|3[AC-Fac-f]|4[05-9A-Fa-f]|5[1-689A-Fa-f]|6[05-9A- |     |
# |     |    | Fa-f]|7[1-689A-Ea-e])))(?:[!'()*\-.0-9A-Z_a-z~]+|(?:% |     |
# |     |    | (?:2[1-9A-Fa-f]|3[AC-Fac-f]|[4-6][0-9A-Fa-f]|7[0-9A-E |     |
# |     |    | a-e])))*)))|(?:;(?:tsp)=(?: |(?:(?:(?:[A-Za-z](?:(?:( |     |
# |     |    | ?:[-A-Za-z0-9]+)){0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?)(?:[.](?:[A-Za-z |     |
# |     |    | ](?:(?:(?:[-A-Za-z0-9]+)){0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?))*))))|( |     |
# |     |    | ?:;(?:(?:[!'*\-.0-9A-Z_a-z~]+|%(?:2[13-7ABDEabde]|3[0 |     |
# |     |    | -9]|4[1-9A-Fa-f]|5[AEFaef]|6[0-9A-Fa-f]|7[0-9ACEace]) |     |
# |     |    | )*)(?:=(?:(?:(?:(?:[!'*\-.0-9A-Z_a-z~]+|%(?:2[13-7ABD |     |
# |     |    | Eabde]|3[0-9]|4[1-9A-Fa-f]|5[AEFaef]|6[0-9A-Fa-f]|7[0 |     |
# |     |    | -9ACEace]))*)(?:[?](?:(?:[!'*\-.0-9A-Z_a-z~]+|%(?:2[1 |     |
# |     |    | 3-7ABDEabde]|3[0-9]|4[1-9A-Fa-f]|5[AEFaef]|6[0-9A-Fa- |     |
# |     |    | f]|7[0-9ACEace]))*))?)|(?:%22(?:(?:%5C(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\- |     |
# |     |    | _.!~*'()]|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])))|[a-zA-Z0-9\-_ |     |
# |     |    | .!~*'()]+|(?:%(?:[01][a-fA-F0-9])|2[013-9A-Fa-f]|[3-9 |     |
# |     |    | A-Fa-f][a-fA-F0-9]))*%22)))?))*))))|(?:(?:ftp)://(?:( |     |
# |     |    | ?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.!~*'();:&=+$,]+|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9] |     |
# |     |    | [a-fA-F0-9]))*))(?:)@)?(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][ |     |
# |     |    | -a-zA-Z0-9]*)?[a-zA-Z0-9])[.])*(?:[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9 |     |
# |     |    | ]*[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z])[.]?)|(?:[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0- |     |
# |     |    | 9]+[.][0-9]+)))(?::(?:(?:[0-9]*)))?(?:/(?:(?:(?:(?:(? |     |
# |     |    | :[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.!~*'():@&=+$,]+|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F |     |
# |     |    | 0-9]))*)(?:/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.!~*'():@&=+$,]+|(?:%[ |     |
# |     |    | a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]))*))*))(?:;type=(?:[AIai]))?))? |     |
# |     |    | )|(?:(?:tv):(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9]*)? |     |
# |     |    | [a-zA-Z0-9])[.])*(?:[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]| |     |
# |     |    | [a-zA-Z])[.]?))?)|(?:(?:news):(?:(?:[*]|(?:(?:[-a-zA- |     |
# |     |    | Z0-9$_.+!*'(),;/?:&=]|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9]))+@( |     |
# |     |    | ?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9]*)?[a-zA-Z0-9])[ |     |
# |     |    | .])*(?:[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z]))|(? |     |
# |     |    | :[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+)))|(?:[a-zA-Z][-A- |     |
# |     |    | Za-z0-9.+_]*))))|(?:(?:fax):(?:(?:(?:[+](?:[0-9\-.()] |     |
# |     |    | +)(?:;isub=[0-9\-.()]+)?(?:;tsub=[0-9\-.()]+)?(?:;pos |     |
# |     |    | td=[0-9\-.()*#ABCDwp]+)?(?:(?:;(?:phone-context)=(?:( |     |
# |     |    | ?:(?:[+][0-9\-.()]+)|(?:[0-9\-.()*#ABCDwp]+))|(?:(?:[ |     |
# |     |    | !'E-OQ-VX-Z_e-oq-vx-z~]|(?:%(?:2[124-7CFcf]|3[AC-Fac- |     |
# |     |    | f]|4[05-9A-Fa-f]|5[1-689A-Fa-f]|6[05-9A-Fa-f]|7[1-689 |     |
# |     |    | A-Ea-e])))(?:[!'()*\-.0-9A-Z_a-z~]+|(?:%(?:2[1-9A-Fa- |     |
# |     |    | f]|3[AC-Fac-f]|[4-6][0-9A-Fa-f]|7[0-9A-Ea-e])))*)))|( |     |
# |     |    | ?:;(?:tsp)=(?: |(?:(?:(?:[A-Za-z](?:(?:(?:[-A-Za-z0-9 |     |
# |     |    | ]+)){0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?)(?:[.](?:[A-Za-z](?:(?:(?:[-A |     |
# |     |    | -Za-z0-9]+)){0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?))*))))|(?:;(?:(?:[!'* |     |
# |     |    | \-.0-9A-Z_a-z~]+|%(?:2[13-7ABDEabde]|3[0-9]|4[1-9A-Fa |     |
# |     |    | -f]|5[AEFaef]|6[0-9A-Fa-f]|7[0-9ACEace]))*)(?:=(?:(?: |     |
# |     |    | (?:(?:[!'*\-.0-9A-Z_a-z~]+|%(?:2[13-7ABDEabde]|3[0-9] |     |
# |     |    | |4[1-9A-Fa-f]|5[AEFaef]|6[0-9A-Fa-f]|7[0-9ACEace]))*) |     |
# |     |    | (?:[?](?:(?:[!'*\-.0-9A-Z_a-z~]+|%(?:2[13-7ABDEabde]| |     |
# |     |    | 3[0-9]|4[1-9A-Fa-f]|5[AEFaef]|6[0-9A-Fa-f]|7[0-9ACEac |     |
# |     |    | e]))*))?)|(?:%22(?:(?:%5C(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.!~*'()]|(?: |     |
# |     |    | %[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])))|[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.!~*'()]+|(?: |     |
# |     |    | %(?:[01][a-fA-F0-9])|2[013-9A-Fa-f]|[3-9A-Fa-f][a-fA- |     |
# |     |    | F0-9]))*%22)))?))*)|(?:[0-9\-.()*#ABCDwp]+(?:;isub=[0 |     |
# |     |    | -9\-.()]+)?(?:;tsub=[0-9\-.()]+)?(?:;postd=[0-9\-.()* |     |
# |     |    | #ABCDwp]+)?(?:;(?:phone-context)=(?:(?:(?:[+][0-9\-.( |     |
# |     |    | )]+)|(?:[0-9\-.()*#ABCDwp]+))|(?:(?:[!'E-OQ-VX-Z_e-oq |     |
# |     |    | -vx-z~]|(?:%(?:2[124-7CFcf]|3[AC-Fac-f]|4[05-9A-Fa-f] |     |
# |     |    | |5[1-689A-Fa-f]|6[05-9A-Fa-f]|7[1-689A-Ea-e])))(?:[!' |     |
# |     |    | ()*\-.0-9A-Z_a-z~]+|(?:%(?:2[1-9A-Fa-f]|3[AC-Fac-f]|[ |     |
# |     |    | 4-6][0-9A-Fa-f]|7[0-9A-Ea-e])))*)))(?:(?:;(?:phone-co |     |
# |     |    | ntext)=(?:(?:(?:[+][0-9\-.()]+)|(?:[0-9\-.()*#ABCDwp] |     |
# |     |    | +))|(?:(?:[!'E-OQ-VX-Z_e-oq-vx-z~]|(?:%(?:2[124-7CFcf |     |
# |     |    | ]|3[AC-Fac-f]|4[05-9A-Fa-f]|5[1-689A-Fa-f]|6[05-9A-Fa |     |
# |     |    | -f]|7[1-689A-Ea-e])))(?:[!'()*\-.0-9A-Z_a-z~]+|(?:%(? |     |
# |     |    | :2[1-9A-Fa-f]|3[AC-Fac-f]|[4-6][0-9A-Fa-f]|7[0-9A-Ea- |     |
# |     |    | e])))*)))|(?:;(?:tsp)=(?: |(?:(?:(?:[A-Za-z](?:(?:(?: |     |
# |     |    | [-A-Za-z0-9]+)){0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?)(?:[.](?:[A-Za-z]( |     |
# |     |    | ?:(?:(?:[-A-Za-z0-9]+)){0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?))*))))|(?: |     |
# |     |    | ;(?:(?:[!'*\-.0-9A-Z_a-z~]+|%(?:2[13-7ABDEabde]|3[0-9 |     |
# |     |    | ]|4[1-9A-Fa-f]|5[AEFaef]|6[0-9A-Fa-f]|7[0-9ACEace]))* |     |
# |     |    | )(?:=(?:(?:(?:(?:[!'*\-.0-9A-Z_a-z~]+|%(?:2[13-7ABDEa |     |
# |     |    | bde]|3[0-9]|4[1-9A-Fa-f]|5[AEFaef]|6[0-9A-Fa-f]|7[0-9 |     |
# |     |    | ACEace]))*)(?:[?](?:(?:[!'*\-.0-9A-Z_a-z~]+|%(?:2[13- |     |
# |     |    | 7ABDEabde]|3[0-9]|4[1-9A-Fa-f]|5[AEFaef]|6[0-9A-Fa-f] |     |
# |     |    | |7[0-9ACEace]))*))?)|(?:%22(?:(?:%5C(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-_. |     |
# |     |    | !~*'()]|(?:%[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])))|[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.! |     |
# |     |    | ~*'()]+|(?:%(?:[01][a-fA-F0-9])|2[013-9A-Fa-f]|[3-9A- |     |
# |     |    | Fa-f][a-fA-F0-9]))*%22)))?))*))))|(?:(?:nntp)://(?:(? |     |
# |     |    | :(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9]*)?[a-zA-Z0 |     |
# |     |    | -9])[.])*(?:[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z] |     |
# |     |    | ))|(?:[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+)))(?::(?:(?:[ |     |
# |     |    | 0-9]+)))?)/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z][-A-Za-z0-9.+_]*))(?:/(?:[0- |     |
# |     |    | 9]+))?)))                                             |     |
# +-----+----+-------------------------------------------------------+-----+
```

Can I do anything to make the output look something like:

```
# +-----+----+-------------------------------------------------------+-----+
# | GOT | OP | CHECK                                                 | LNs |
# +-----+----+-------------------------------------------------------+-----+
# | foo | =~ | $RE{URI}                                              | 1   |
# +-----+----+-------------------------------------------------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is not possible to format the check message. Looking at the source:

- [Test2::Tools::Compare::is()](https://metacpan.org/release/Test2-Suite/source/lib/Test2/Tools/Compare.pm#L78) calls
- [Test2::Compare::Delta::diag()](https://metacpan.org/release/Test2-Suite/source/lib/Test2/Compare/Delta.pm#L324) which calls
- [Test2::Compare::Delta::table()](https://metacpan.org/release/Test2-Suite/source/lib/Test2/Compare/Delta.pm#L277) to format the output.

You may try ask for a new feature at the GitHub [issue tracker](https://github.com/Test-More/Test2-Suite/issues).